# If else statement to set different listadaptor

Tags: android, json, if-statement, android-listview

I'm trying to set an if-else statement to make a chat app with JSON, I want to make the if-else statement read the JSON and place it in labels where I want them to be.

Imagine like this, I am "A" and I chat with person "B".

IF the message comes from "B" (not me) it puts the message to labels aligned to the right in the listview. ELSE - When I sends a message it is put to left labels inside the listview.

The strings I use in the statement is "TAG_FACEBOOK".

My listadaptor:

```
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_CONTEXT, TAG_FACEBOOK }, new int[] {
                    R.id.context, R.id.facebook });

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I've tried solving it using a if-else statement like this:

```
if (TAG_FACEBOOK == "B"){
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_CONTEXT, TAG_FACEBOOK }, new int[] {
                    R.id.context, R.id.facebook });

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
else {
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_CONTEXT, TAG_FACEBOOK }, new int[] {
                    R.id.contextL, R.id.facebookL });

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

But Eclipse tells me it's "dead code". 
How should I do?

Comment: your if-statement seems to be wrong, try using if (TAG_FACEBOOK.equals("B")), as this is the standard way of comparing Strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TAG_FACEBOOK == "B"` compare only references, not the String content.

Use `TAG_FACEBOOK.equals("B")`.

Answer (score 1):

First, in Java you compare two strings (s1 and s2) using the method:

```
s1.equals(s2)
```

Second, Eclipse is telling you it is dead code because TAG_FACEBOOK is constant.  You need this string to be dynamic based on the user, that way it will actually be possible to reach both the if or the else block, depending on the string.

Answer (score 1):

So use `.equals()` for string comparison like the other people have mentioned, but it sounds to me like your adapter is the one that should be checking on which side of the screen the view should be rendered (inside the `getView()` method).

Answer (score -3):

```
//This is array list
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

//Now if-else statement which providing details of list if list is matching then it
//will to go the activityone if not matching it will go to the activitytwo.
if (list.size() != 0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activityone.class);
    intent.putExtra("key", list);
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    String string = " ";
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activitytwo.class);
    i.putExtra("key1", string);
    startActivity(i);
}
```